# Sharing Bad Words On Blog Post

Tags: sharing

I have a *bad (spam) words* list for spam protection filters. I want to share them with my blog readers. I will put this list to my blog post but i'm worring about something.

There will be a lot of *bad word* on my post, because of this will Google ban me ?

How can i put this list to my post ? inside of `<blockquote>` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a TXT file and link it as downloadable? Or even better XML or JSON if you don't mind people linking to it.

Surely you don't want to post them :)

Answer (score 1):

Google might not ding you but some other "family protection" proxy apps will.  Also, this is just going to serve as a handy guide to people looking for words that are *not* on your list, probably doing more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the HTML pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_pre.asp).

Comment: No, it won't ignore, but the pre tag will allow you to format them so that the list so that the word is still understood without actually spelling it. You can put slashes in front of the vowels, or something along those lines.